# Проверка включен ли JS

Tags: php, javascript

Люди есть такая задачка. Выполнять одну функцию, если яваскрипт включен в обозревателе и выполнять другую если выключен. Как реализовать средствами PHP? Есть до ужаса дурацкая идея - создать на JS переменную, потом передать ей в php. Потом проверить на пустоту этой переменной средствами php. Соответственно, если JS отключено то переменная будет пуста, потому, как скрипт ничего не передаст, а если передаст то будет с данными. Так можно вычислить включен JS или нет? Кто может помочь написать такую функцию?

Comment: Я думаю куда проще будет мыслить в направлении "загрузить одну стринцу или другую", а не с функциями. Воспользоваться тегом `<noscript>`.

Comment: Да нет... в том то и дело... что в данной сложившейся ситуации... когда используется дофига класов и циклов для вывода определенной информации нужно именно такое решение... Вот поэтому и надо сделать именно так...

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
@session_start();
$_SESSION['JS_ON'] = (!empty($_SESSION['JS_ON']) || !empty($_GET['js'])); // JS_ON будет == true, если он уже установлен в сессии или только что пришел get-запрос
if (!$_SESSION['JS_ON'] && empty($_SESSION['JS_CHECKED'])) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href="?js=1";</script>';
  $_SESSION['JS_CHECKED'] = 1;
  } // если еще не проверяли, добавляем переадресацию

?>
```

Т.о. при первом попадании на сайт человек, у которого включен JS, будет переадресован (1 раз) и у вас будет переменная `$_SESSION['JS_ON']` - соответственно, включен ли javascript или нет.

Answer (score 1):

```
$browser = get_browser();
// Преобразовать $browser в массив 
$browser = (array) $browser;
if ($browser["javascript"] == 1) :
print "Javascript enabled!";
else :
print "No javascript allowed!";
endif;
```

Comment: [get_browser()][1] — читаем примечание, а также описание функции. 

[1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php

Comment: да, забыл упомянуть, но как вариант - имеет место быть

Answer (score 1):

Функция `get_browser()` сообщает о возможностях браузера пользователя, то есть если браузер работает с `js` то `$browser["javascript"]` всегда будет равно 1, но это не значит что в настройках браузера `javascript` не отключен пользователем.